# How can I insert multiple rows in the entity with foreign key? (one to many relationship not working as expected)

Tags: java, android, foreign-keys, android-room

I have two entities. One for the whole game and one for the stats (from player and rounds).

The `Game` entity uses the gameNumber (total games played) as key and gives the `Stats` entity the value as foreign key (so if I delete a game, the stats will be deleted as well)

And the `Stats` entity uses a string key. Everything looks like this:

Game:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "Game")
public class Game {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "GameId")
    int gameId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "WinnerNumber")
    int winnerNumber;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "PlayerCount")
    int playerCount;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Points")
    int points;

    public Game(int gameId, int winnerNumber, int playerCount, int points) {
        this.gameId = gameId;
        this.winnerNumber= winnerNumber;
        this.playerCount = playerCount;
        this.points = points;
    }

    //getter
}
```

Stats:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "Stats", foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Game.class, parentColumns = "GameId", childColumns = "GameNumber", onDelete = CASCADE), indices = @Index(value = "GameNumber"))
public class Stats {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Key")
    @NonNull
    public String key;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "GameNumber")
    public int gameNumber;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "PlayerCount")
    private int playerCount;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "PlayerNumber")
    private int playerNumber;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Round")
    private int round;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Sum")
    public int sumPoints;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "PointArray")
    private String points;

    public Stats(int gameNumber, int playerCount, int playerNumber, int round, int sumPoints, String points, String key) {
        this.playerCount = playerCount;
        this.player = player;
        this.round = round;
        this.sumPoints = sumPoints;
        this.points = points;
        this.key = key;
        this.gameNumber = gameNumber;
    }

    //getter
}
```

DAO:

```java
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(Stats stats);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertGame(Game game);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Stats WHERE GameNumber = (SELECT MAX(GameNumber) FROM Stats)")
    List<Stats> getLastStats();

    @Query("SELECT GameId FROM Game WHERE GameId = (SELECT MAX(GameId) FROM Game)")
    int getLastGameId();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Stats WHERE GameNumber= (SELECT MAX(GameId) FROM Game) AND PlayerNumber LIKE :playerNumber")
    List<Stats> getLastPlayerStats(int playerNumber);
```

Now is the question how i correctly insert stats for one game.
For that I currently do this:

```java
try {
   gameId = model.getLastGameId() + 1;
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
   gameId = 0;
}

   Game game = new Game(gameId, 0, 2, 10) 
   dao.insertGame(game)

   Stats stats = new Stats(game.getGameId(), 2, 0, 1, 10, "10, 2", 201) // 0 = playerNumber
   dao.insert(stats)

   Stats stats = new Stats(game.getGameId(), 2, 1, 1, 5, "5, 1", 211) // 1 = playerNumber
   dao.insert(stats)
```

While testing in another class I got this:

```java
List<Stats> listPlayer0 = getLastPlayerStats(0);
int size = listPlayer0.size(); //size = 0

List<Stats> listPlayer1 = getLastPlayerStats(1);
int size1 = listPlayer1; //size1 = 1

List<Stats> listTotal = getLastStats();
int totalSize = listTotal.size() //totalSize = 1
```

Obviously just the last entry gets stored

I tried:

1. deleting the parameter `int gameNumber` in Stats Constructor:

Got: `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)`Error

2. Deleting foreign key annonation:

Everything works fine except the fact that if I delete a game, the stats are still there.

So I guess something with the foreign key goes wrong. But what and why? In connection with that: Would it be better to use Relationships? What's the difference?